# What's the formula to estimate the shape parameter of Pareto distribution using weighted least squares method?

Tags: weighted-regression, pareto-distribution, fat-tails

I'm trying to simulate my own method using R to estimate the shape parameter of Pareto distributed data by weighted least squares. I searched via several links of research papers, but I could not find any formula.

https://www.kau.edu.sa/Files/0009071/Researches/62369_33387.pdf

What I need is a straightforward formula to compute the weights and the the estimate of the shape parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this myself.
http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~adamw/papers/2013-SIGMETRICS-heavytails.pdf
Answer is in page 84, where ri/n = sample proportion of number of X's greater than or equal to xi

Comment: We prefer this site to be mostly self-contained, so please can you add the main content of that paper directly in the answer, with $\LaTeX$?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I'm finding it difficult to edit with latex. Would accept any edit.

Comment: Did you find some time to learn $\LaTeX$ now?